# Count and Delete Each Substring Occurrence

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm writing a program which counts and then deletes the occurrence of a substring. Both these operations are done one at a time.

This however doesn't work for all cases:

*Works Correctly*:

```
string = abbab
substring = ab
Occurrences = 2
```

*Doesn't Work*:

```
string = abab
substring = ab
Occurrences: 1    # should be 2
```

Below is the code:

```
def count_delete(string, substring):
    occurrence = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i:i + len(substring)] == substring:
            occurrence += 1
            string = string.replace(substring, "", 1)
    return occurrence

def main():
    string = 'abbab'
    substring = 'ab'
    count = count_delete(string, substring)
    print("Occurrences:", count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I get the correct output in all cases ?

Comment: Why do you modify `string` if you are not returning it? Move that replace line to just after the for loop and replace all occurences by removing the 1 parameter

Comment: @RichieV count and delete have to be done in a successive manner as per the problem statement.

Comment: Link to the problem statement, please.

Comment: @RichieV Then it would count overlapping occurrences.

Comment: I think people are not registering the following use cases. Case 1: String: aaa, pattern: aa, result: a.  Case 2: String: ababa, pattern aba, result: ba.  Read first and delete later CAN work, as long as you skip i when reading (i.e. if found, i += pattern.length - 1) so as to not detect overlapping matches, but not by using library calls such as findAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for i in range(len(string)): ***** 1
        if string[i:i + len(substring)] == substring: ***** 3
            occurrence += 1
            string = string.replace(substring, "", 1) ***** 2
```

Your bug is on the lines I marked.

On line ***** 2, you delete the substring you just found.  Then on ***** 1, you will increment i.  If substring immediately follows substring, you will not detect it, as your i variable has progressed.

I would suggest the following modification to make your existing code work:

1. Find all instances of substring and mark the locations without modifying.
2. Delete all substrings starting from the rear based on the locations marked in the previous step.

Alternatively, change ***** 3 to a while loop.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the bug. I've changed `if` to a `while` loop.

Comment: Using the above code for `abababb` will give you `occurrence = 2` and the problem is that you are using `i` in your `if statement`. You should use `[:len(substring)]` instead of `[i:i+len(substring)]`.  I didnt vote down but want you to please correct the code. This code will NOT provide the correct result

Comment: @JoeFerndz for `string=abababb` and `substring=ab`, I'm getting `Occurrences: 3`. Note that as per @John 's suggestion, I've changed `if` to `while`.

Comment: The code is the OP's code copy/pasted with lines marked.  I did not make any modifications to the original code, but pasted there to reference line numbers, so there's nothing to correct.  Once the OP changes his code he's running, he will not run into the issue of consecutive pattern detection.

Comment: @John, sorry about that. I didn't realize you were referring to OP code. @Saurabh, if you tried your original code, `string = abababb` and `substring = ab` will give `Occurrences: 2`

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes, that was the bug.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re
string = 'abbcab'
substring = 'ab'

print(len(re.findall(r''+substring,string)))
#2

print(re.sub(r''+substring,'',string))
#bc

# Update: It seems  simple string manipulation  would do the task.
print(string.count(substring))
print(string.replace(substring,''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def count_delete(string, substring):
    '''
    >>> print(count_delete('aabbcab', 'ab'))
    (2, 'abc')
    '''
    occurrence = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(string):
        if string[i:i + len(substring)] == substring:
            occurrence += 1
            # string = string.replace(substring, "", 1) # replaces from index 0
            string = string[:i] + string[i+len(substring):]
            # substring was removed, so we keep i on the same position
        else:
            i += 1
            # substring not found, try next position
    return occurrence, string
```

This is only for training purposes, to understand the behavior of loops on iterables that are changed in-loop

The pythonic way is to count all and then replace all, or better, regex and capture all

---

this also works

```
def split_join(string, substring):
    '''
    >>> print(split_join('aabbcab', 'ab'))
    (2, 'abc')
    '''
    split = string.split(substring)
    return len(split) - 1, ''.join(split)
```

Comment: You should NOT search the string from `i` since you are trimming the string. This logic is not correct. Please see my answer for explanation.

Comment: @superb thank you for pointing that out, `.replace` finds the first occurrence from index0, and in this case a new occurrence was formed by removing `substring` in a previous iteration

Answer (score 0):

Since you throw away the reduced string and only report the number of occurrences, there's a much simpler and faster way to do that:

```
>>> 'abbab'.count('ab')
2
>>> 'abab'.count('ab')
2
```

Comment: @John It produces 1. Why didn't you just try it? It's far less to type than your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code may work better for you:

```
def count_del(string, substring):
    occurs = 0

    #using the find method to increment counter
    #if -1, no substring found, if 0 or >0, substring found
    #increment counter and search to the right of substring

    while string.find(substring) >= 0:
        string = string[string.find(substring) + len(substring):]

        #truncate all strings until substring + len(substring)
        #search only items in the right of substring

        occurs +=1
    return occurs
```

=========
leaving my older code and comments as there is reference in the comments to this section.

Every time you go into the loop, you are decreasing the length of the string. That messes up your value of `i` in the if statement.

`if string[i:i + len(substring)] == substring:`

When you go into the loop for the first time, `i` is `0`, therefore, your if statement converts to:

`if string[0:0 + 2] == substring:`

When you go into the loop for the second time, `i` is 1, therefore, your if statement converts to:

`if string[1:1 + 2] == substring:`

I don't think this is what you want to do. You still want to search from 0 instead of 1.

If you change your code as follows, it will give you the desired result

```
def count_delete(string, substring):
    occurrence = 0
    while len(string) >= len(substring):
    #for i in range(len(string)):   replaced for loop with while
        #check the string from beginning to len of substring
        if string[:len(substring)] == substring:
            occurrence += 1
            #string = string.replace(substring, "", 1)
        #instead of removing the entire substring, 
        #you may want to check if there are more occurrences of the same
        #to do that, use the below line

        string = string[1:]

        #this will find 2 'abab' in 'abababb' instead of 1
        #if thats what you want
    return occurrence
```

Comment: You can replace `#string = string.replace(substring, "", 1)` with `string = string[len(substring):]` and it will give you the same result.

Comment: you propose a different interpretation of the problem, which is also correct... your code however, will loop indefinitely unless the string is an exact multiple of substring (e.g. 'abababc' / 'ab' will get stuck on 'c' and never break)

Comment: @RichieV, thanks. didnt catch that. my bad. Thanks. Fixed the code.  Also, I think if the question is just to find the occurrences of a string, the simplest is to do a count.

Comment: your edit still doesn't break with string `abababb` substring `b`... and I agree, but I think the purpose of this exercise is to raise awareness on the risks of simultaneously looping+modifying an iterable